# winapi window doesn't refresh after painting

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Hi I created a window with this:

```
WNDCLASSEX WndClass = {0};

if (WndClass.cbSize == 0)
{
    WndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    WndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    WndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    WndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WndClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    WndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WndClass.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    WndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    WndClass.lpszClassName = ClassName.c_str();
    WndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
}

if (RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
{

    WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), WindowName.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if(WindowHandle)
    {
        ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    }
}
```

And try to add a button. Use this:

```
HWND child = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, n * CHILDS_OFSET, posY, GetWidth(), h, window, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

After code executed my window stays clear, but if I move it or resize it, button becomes visible, what the issue might be?

I tried:

```
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(window, &rc);
InvalidateRect(window, &rc, TRUE);
```

Tried if `window` is handle to the main window and to the button.

Comment: What's in your WindowProcedure? This could happen if you don't handle `WM_PAINT` properly.

Comment: @jlahd Probably here is mistake, I'm new on WinAPI GUI so found an example where is no `WM_PAINT` handling, just `break`, how should it be handled?

Comment: @user2623967 I strongly recommend reading the step-by-step tutorials here: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Comment: Using string::c_str() to generate a C string that must remain stable for the life of the app is a practice you'll regret some day.

Comment: @Hans I don't see why the two `std::string`s need to be stable or even be alive once `RegisterClassEx` and `CreateWindowEx` have returned.

Comment: It is the practice that's fishy.  Hard rule in this case is that it must remain stable until UnregisterClass() is called.  The one that nobody ever calls.

Comment: @Hans I don't see that hard rule spelled out in the documentation nor even a hint towards that. On the contrary I would assume that the `WNDCLASSEX` structure is copied to kernel memory, which includes copying all contained strings. I would be surprised to find out that random user-land pointers got stored in kernel space. Do you have any references that outline how `RegisterClassEx` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if your window procedure does not handle `WM_PAINT` properly. The minimum thing you must have is

```
...
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        BeginPaint( wnd, &ps );
        EndPaint( wnd, &ps );
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, works fine. It should be included in all beginners tutorials for WinAPI GUI.

Comment: It is, there are hundreds of WinAPI GUI tutorials, often with sample apps, you are just not looking hard enough for them.

Here's a site that covers some legacy topics that barely anyone uses any more. http://www.functionx.com/win32/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call [`UpdateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after `ShowWindow`, see [here](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/).